# Blender is outputting blank screen video with no audio

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, audio

I am working on a project that has multiple simultaneous sound files and image video files layered over each other, I'm not sure if this effects what I have to do to output. When I try to render, the output is a file that is the length of my project, but displays a blank screen with no audio. I have the following settings set:
-File format: FFmpeg
-Encoding: MPEG-4
-Video Codec: H.264
-Output quality: High quality
-Audio Codec: AAC
I have the file saved in a folder where I know I can find it, and I also do have all of the frames selected in my project from start to end so I know that's not causing the problem.
Any thoughts on this issue would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance! [image]

Comment: Does your System console say anything? What is your resolution? Does the same thing happen if you export as image sequence?

Comment: @tintwotin Thank you for your response! Forgive my ignorance but where can I check the system console? The resolution is 1080 x 1920, and I was able to render a video that only had one line of audio and video at a time earlier in the day

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186586/video-sequence-editor-rendering-a-grey-video